# How to Iterate object and push data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

data getting

```
data = {
  sample1//object{
     results :{
       name:'name1',
       label:'label1'   
    },
    {
       name:'name1',
       label:'label1'   
    }
  }
 sample2//object
   results :{
       name:'name1',
       label:'label1'   
    },
    {
       name:'name1',
       label:'label1'   
    }

}
```

what i am doing is

```
for ( var name in data )
{
    $scope.model.datalist.push(data[name]);
}
console.log($scope.model.datalist) - >
    result : results :{
           name:'name1',
           label:'label1'   
        },  (all reslults)
```

But i want to add key name aswell ,like

```
results :{
           name:'name1',
           label:'label1',
           key:'sample1'//(if sample1)
        },
```

please guide how do this .here sample1 and sample2 are dynamic ,it may come other name also for main object

Comment: You're looking for `Array.prototype.map`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map and don't iterate arrays with `for... in`, always `for`, `for... of` (new) `angular.each` (angular specific) or `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Comment: Your example `data` is in a format I've never seen and is not a valid JavaScript object. Please provide an example of the actual data you're working with in a valid format.

Comment: Do not format your question statements as code. It gets confusing. If you must write something with your code, write it as a // comment.

Comment: Your data is array or json?

Comment: Please format sample data structure and expected sample output

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.forEach(arrayOfObjects, function(singleObject){
    singleObject.dynamicKey = dynamicValue;
});
```